# Vertical align not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've prepared a fiddle for you, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/VvkQd/1/

I wan't that red "bottom" to be at the bottom of this td.
What its not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add position relative to that `<td>` and absolutely position the text you want. It's not the most elegant solution but neither are tables..

http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/VvkQd/4/

Comment: Um, now; when there is much text in the second col, the text is overlapping over the "Bottom" text. Any solution?

Comment: add padding-bottom to that `<td>` enough to overlap the size of the `<div>`

Comment: sorry but I got next problem: I used `padding-bottom` there, but this text "Bottom" is user-specified, so user may type some large text and small font-texts, if it happends , it looks kinda bugged and overlapp too - i'll have to change padding-bottom depends on the text that user specified.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical-align is for it's content so even if you set it on a div, and if the div was bigger it won't even work, I suggest adding another tr

http://jsfiddle.net/HNhy9/

Hope you'll find a best answer ... Maybe you should work only with div

Answer (score 1):

Rowspan would do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/VvkQd/1/